# objective-c swipe from outside phone

Tags: objective-c, user-experience, uiswipegesturerecognizer

apps like google chrome for iphone support a special type of swipe.
you swipe from the outside of the phone to the middle (from left to right, or other way round)
and a specific action is triggered (chrome: navigation between browser tabs).

is this a built in gesture (swipe gesture start outside phone), or do i need to code this by hand?

thanks in advance
Alex

EDIT
here its explained on ipad (4:40)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=tss9ZlIMrOA#t=284s

Comment: What do you mean by "Swipe from the outside of the phone" ?

Comment: You have to code it manually. If what you're after though is some kind of slide panel you'll find many open source projects around providing this functionality.

Comment: @vin added a video with an ipad showcase. cant find the iphone showcase for this.

Answer (score 0):

ok - looks like its not built in. just for completion - here is the code.
put it in your navigationcontroller

```
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped:)];
    [swipeRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
}

-(void)swiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRecognizer
{
    CGPoint loc = [swipeRecognizer locationInView: self.view];

    // if swipe was from side of screen
    if(loc.x <= 20)
    {
        if(self.viewControllers.count > 2)
            [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```